# Using cfpop to access gmail in CF8

Tags: coldfusion, gmail, coldfusion-8

So I need to use ColdFusion 8 to check a GMail account for emails, eventually I'll download the attachments. I've Googled and not found much except for the following code. What bugs me is that, that's all I've found.

So is this the best way to go?

Here is the code. I've included the link but there is not much more information.

```
<cfscript>
    javaSystem = createObject( "java", "java.lang.System" );
    jProps = javaSystem.getProperties();
    jProps.setProperty( "mail.pop3.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory" );
    jProps.setproperty( "mail.pop3.port", 995 );
    jProps.setProperty( "mail.pop3.socketFactory.port", 995 );
</cfscript>

<cfpop action="getheaderonly" name="rsEmail" startrow="1? maxrows="50" server="pop.gmail.com" port="995" username="your@username.com.au" password="yourpassword">
```

[Using CFPOP to check mail on GMail](http://australiansearchengine.wordpress.com/2009/05/24/cfpop-gmail/)

Comment: Thanks everyone for the responses. I've chosen to go with this approach i.e: using POP. Although the other approaches from answers are good. Using POP is simple and I don't need to do anything except get the attachments from the email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work but you should know that it sets the GLOBAL SSL socketfactory for POP3. I believe this will have a serverwide affect - which may be irrelevant to your process but it is worth noting.

Comment: Ah that might be an issue. I believe that there are other things on the server that use POP3. I would imagine that issue is quite difficult to diagnose.

Comment: yep :) You current approach is setting system wide properties using java.lang.System. You can likely use a pure java implementation that does not set system properties but rather implements the socket factory per request - but I don't have any sample for you. I'd try barnyr approach first - see if Imap gives you what you want eh?

Comment: Yeah maybe thats a better approach. Thanks so much anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Is there a reason you need to use POP in particular? If you're on CF9, then you can use [CFIMAP](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WS371453EC-36D5-44ce-BF1E-750E3016BBD6.html) which ought to work with gmail. The docs even use gmail as an example.

Alternatively, you could use the javamail API directly:

```
<cfscript>
props = CreateObject("java","java.util.Properties").init();
props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");

sessClass = CreateObject("java","javax.mail.Session");

sess = sessClass.getDefaultInstance(props);

store = sess.getStore("imaps");
store.connect("imap.googlemail.com","you@gmail.com", "password");

folder = store.getFolder("inbox");

if(!folder.isOpen()){
          folder.open(folder.READ_WRITE)
}

messageCount = folder.getMessageCount();

dump(messageCount);

if (!IsNull(folder) && folder.isOpen()) { folder.close(true); }

if (!IsNull(store)) { store.close(); }  

</cfscript>
```

Comment: Just checked (forgot I could check by dumping the SERVER variable). We're currently running CF 8. There is a plan to move to upgrade, but not for some time. So I'm stuck at 8 for this solution.

Comment: You could go direct to Java and see if you can use the JavaMail IMAP connectivity, but as Mark notes, this is changing a global setting also. Here's a nice short example, which should convert to CF quickly: http://harikrishnan83.wordpress.com/2009/01/24/access-gmail-with-imap-using-java-mail-api/

Comment: Actually, having read the example link I just posted, it's only using the global System Properties object as a convenient way of getting a properties object. You could probably instantiate your own properties object and populate that with the necessary connection details

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly use the opensource cfgmail project on Riaforge:

http://cfgmail.riaforge.org/

It works both in CF 7 and up.